# Target of URI doesn't exist:'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

on adding flutter_screenutil package version 1.0.2 ,the "target of URI doesn't exist" error is being showed i have tried the latest  flutter_screenutil: ^4.0.2+1 package also but both give the same error . How to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

I assume youre using Visual Studio Code.

Restarting Visual Studio Code after

```
flutter pub get
```

This will do it.

You can also check the library of flutter on using packages
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: I have tried this method but still it shows the error